# Want to clear UIWebView cache from server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, objective-c

I have created an HTML page. From my iPhone app I am using that URL in my `UIWebView`.

Here I want to set a code in my HTML, in which I can tell `UIWebView` not to use cache. Or I want to tell URL not to use cache.

If I am not able to explain you correctly, free to ask me.

Comment: See if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744644/uiwebview-without-cache) -- duplicate if you ask me.

Answer (score 3):

Clean the `HTML` document by removing all content

```
  [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML='';"];
```

Or  Flush all cached data like bellow..

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

For more information see this blog [UIWebView-secrets-part](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/04/UIWebView-secrets-part2-leaks-on-release/)

Comment: I want to do this from server side. I want to do a code in my HTMl file. So suggest me a HTML solution/code.

Comment: hey try this like some something <script src='myurl?t=1234'> ... see the answer of TomSwift may be you want that dude.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523435/how-to-clear-uiwebview-cache/14096331#14096331

Comment: @Helenvoy now you got it dude??

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to disable cache by looking at an info on html or url. I suggest you to place this info in HTML between unique tags. You could parse it using string operations after.

If you are using url you should use something like query string.

Finally disabling cache is done by

```
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
```

However this code disables cache for good. If you want to enable it again you should set disk capacity and memory capacity to a higher value.

Comment: I want to do this from server side. I want to do a code in my HTMl file. So suggest me a HTML solution/code.