# How to delete webview cached history?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, browser-history, uiwebviewdelegate

I am loading different news items in webview from seperate links. If user switches from one link to other, I need to clear the old data and reset my go forward and backward buttons. so that webview canGoBack and canGoForward methods return NO. How can I do something like [webView clearCache]? Is it possible in iOS 7?

Comment: Does the cache important for you at all ?

Comment: The previous and next button takes me to the previous and next news article respectively. However, if I switch through them the buttons at top for webview navigation gets activated which jumbles up the news ids I am recieving from server for exact particular articles. I want to disable those top right buttons in order to avoid irrelevant  navigation when somebody presses the buttons at bottom.

Comment: As you can see I have disabled previous button when I don't have news item in the array of articles. However, top right first button is enabled as there is still data in webview history. What to do for such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing caches is not so good because user can be load the same article few time.

So it will be better if you check navigation type in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` If is `UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther` then back button should be disabled because it is not user caused navigation

But if you still want to clear cache see this question: [How to clear UIWebView cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2523435/1403732)